# How can I count fields in a JSON based on their content

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to JS an this is likely a noob question, but I can't seem to find an answer which I figure may be due to my lack of correct terminology.

Basically I'm trying to count how many "active" fields in a JSON file are set to true vs false and return those values to a variable. I'm just getting lost trying to figure out how to go about this.

For example, my JSON is named **data** and looks like this:

```
{
"systems": [
    {
        "name": "SV001",
        "IP": "10.1.1.101",
        "active": "true"
    },
    {
        "name": "SV002",
        "IP": "10.1.1.102",
        "active": "true"
    },
    {
        "name": "SV003",
        "IP": "10.1.1.103",
        "active": "false"
    }
]}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could use `var json = JSON.parse(jsonString)` to convert your string to a js object. Then use a `for` loop to make the count

Comment: you could do as Claudio suggests and then one line it: `json.map(function(a){return a.active == "true" ? 1 : 0}).reduce(function(a,b){return a+b})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse into the json object from string like
`var json=JSON.parse(jsonString);` And than by looping you can get the value.

```
var count=0;
for(var i=0i<json.systems.length;i++){
  if(json.systems[i].active){
    count++;
  }
}
```

you can have count at the end of loop.

Comment: This did the trick. And with the addition of an **else** parameter, it also reports how many are false, which is terrific. I understand how the **for** loop works,but can you explain how it knows to check if the **active** field is true/false without explicitly being told what to look for?